Troube Creating a GStreamer Pipeline With Preview and Video Record on Command in Python
I'm trying to build a demo pipeline in GStreamer that can read a V4L2 source and show a video preview while enabling start/stop video recording to a file at will.  I have the following code that can:

Show video preview
Start video recording
Stop video recording

However, the stop_recording() function does not successfully get a message to the bus so the finalize() function is never run and the recording bin does not get removed/destroyed.  This means that I can only start/stop recording one time rather than being able to record at will.
I am creating a pipeline with a tee, one side going to the preview and the other side going to a bin which handles encoding and writing to a filesink.  The filesink bin is meant to get created and destroyed upon recieving start/stop commands respectively from the user:
import gi
import sys
from datetime import datetime

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GLib

Gst.init(None)

class VideoCapture:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("pipeline")

        self.source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("v4l2src", "source")
        self.caps = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "caps")

        self.tee = Gst.ElementFactory.make("tee", "tee")

        self.convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "convert")
        # self.display_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("xvimagesink", "sink")
        self.display_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("fakesink", "sink")

        if not self.pipeline or not self.source or not self.caps or not self.convert or not self.display_sink:
            print("Not all file pipeline elements could be created.", file=sys.stderr)
            return

        # Set properties on the source
        self.source.set_property("io-mode", 4)
        self.source.set_property("device", "/dev/video0")
        self.source.set_property("do-timestamp", True)
        self.source.set_property("num-buffers", 10000)

        # Set caps filter properties
        self.caps.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1, format=UYVY"))

        self.tee.set_property("allow-not-linked", True)

        self.pipeline.add(self.source)
        self.pipeline.add(self.caps)
        self.pipeline.add(self.tee)
        self.pipeline.add(self.convert)
        self.pipeline.add(self.display_sink)

        self.source.link(self.caps)
        self.caps.link(self.tee)
        self.tee.link(self.convert)
        self.convert.link(self.display_sink)
        self.is_recording = False
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    def start_recording(self):
        if self.is_recording:
            print("Already recording")
            return
        
        print("Start Recording...")
        self.teepad = self.tee.get_request_pad("src_1")

        self.record_bin = Gst.Bin.new()

        self.queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "queue")
        self.file_convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvvidconv", "file-convert")
        self.video_capture_cap = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "video_capture_cap")
        self.video_capture_encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvv4l2h264enc", "encoder")
        self.parser = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse", "parser")
        self.muxer = Gst.ElementFactory.make("matroskamux", "muxer")
        self.filesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", "filesink")

        if not self.queue or not self.file_convert or not self.video_capture_encoder \
            or not self.muxer or not self.filesink or not self.parser or not self.video_capture_cap:
            print("Not all file pipeline elements could be created.", file=sys.stderr)
            return

        self.video_capture_cap.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=I420"))
        self.video_capture_encoder.set_property("bitrate", 20000000)
        self.filesink.set_property("location", "EO_video_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S_%s") + ".mkv")

        self.record_bin.add(self.queue)
        self.record_bin.add(self.file_convert)
        self.record_bin.add(self.video_capture_cap)
        self.record_bin.add(self.video_capture_encoder)
        self.record_bin.add(self.parser)
        self.record_bin.add(self.muxer)
        self.record_bin.add(self.filesink)
        
        self.queue.link(self.file_convert)
        self.file_convert.link(self.video_capture_cap)
        self.video_capture_cap.link(self.video_capture_encoder)
        self.video_capture_encoder.link(self.parser)
        self.parser.link(self.muxer)
        self.muxer.link(self.filesink)

        self.queue.sync_state_with_parent()
        self.file_convert.sync_state_with_parent()
        self.video_capture_cap.sync_state_with_parent()
        self.video_capture_encoder.sync_state_with_parent()
        self.parser.sync_state_with_parent()
        self.muxer.sync_state_with_parent()
        self.filesink.sync_state_with_parent()
        
        self.pipeline.add(self.record_bin)

        # Create a ghost pad for the bin and link the queue sink pad to the ghost pad
        self.queue_sink_pad = self.queue.get_static_pad("sink")
        self.ghost_pad = Gst.GhostPad.new("sink", self.queue_sink_pad)
        self.record_bin.add_pad(self.ghost_pad)
        self.teepad.link(self.ghost_pad)
        self.record_bin.sync_state_with_parent()
        self.queue_sink_pad.unref()

        self.src_bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.src_bus.add_signal_watch()
        self.src_bus.connect("message", self.on_message)
        self.src_bus.unref()
        self.record_bin.set_property("message-forward", True)


        self.is_recording = True

    def unlink_cb(self, pad, info, userdata):
        print("Unlinking...")
        self.sinkpad = self.record_bin.get_static_pad("sink")
        pad.unlink(self.sinkpad)
        print("Pad unlinked.")
        
        self.record_bin.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
        self.sinkpad.unref()
        
        print("Event sent.")
        return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK

    def stop_recording(self):
        print("Stop Recording...")
        self.teepad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, self.unlink_cb, None)
        self.is_recording = False

    def finalize(self):
        print("Finalizing...")

        # Destroy Bin
        self.record_bin.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        print("Removing...")
        self.pipeline.remove(self.record_bin)

        self.is_recording = False
        print("Unlinked.")

    def on_message(self, bus, message):
        print("message received.")
        t = message.type
        if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
            print("EOS received.")
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        elif t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
            err, debug = message.parse_error()
            print(f"Error: {err}, {debug}", file=sys.stderr)
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        elif t == Gst.MessageType.WARNING:
            err, debug = message.parse_error()
            print(f"Warning: {err}, {debug}", file=sys.stderr)
        elif t == Gst.MessageType.ELEMENT:
            err, debug = message.parse_error()
            print(f"Element message received: {err}, {debug}")
            s = message.get_structure()
            if (s.has_name("GstBinForwarded")):
                forward_msg = s.get_value("message")
                if (Gst.MessageType(forward_msg) == Gst.MessageType.EOS.value):
                    print(f"EOS from element {forward_msg.src.name}")
                    self.finalize()
    def run(self):
        loop = GLib.MainLoop()
        try:
            loop.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_capture = VideoCapture()
    video_capture.run()
    print("Press 's' to start recording, 't' to stop recording, and 'q' to quit.")
    while True:
        command = input()
        if command == 's':
            video_capture.start_recording()
        elif command == 't':
            video_capture.stop_recording()
        elif command == 'q':
            break
    video_capture.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
